# ActiveRecord/Ruby - has_many through has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have an `Event` model, which needs to have `items` in it. An example Event might have 10 tickets and 5 balloons where tickets and balloons are of an `Item` model. I have it set up so that there is an `ItemDatum` Model, that has all of the `items` in an event along with a hash that keeps track of how many of each item there are.

My problem is in the `Event` model associations, where i have:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :location

    has_one :item_datum, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :items, through: :item_datum, source: :event
end
```

but when trying to add items to an `@event.items` var, I get the error: `Could not find the association :item_datum in model Event`.

This is my `Event` migration:

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :text

      t.integer :location_id
      t.integer :item_datum_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

`Item` model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :item_datum

    validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 1 }
    validates :description, presence: true
    validates :item_type, presence: true

end
```

`ItemDatum` model

```
class ItemDatum < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :event
    has_many :items
end
```

And I was trying to add the `items` to the `event` like so:

```
@event = Event.first;
@item = Item.first;
@event.items << @item;
```

Comment: Show the `ItemDatum` and `Item` associations in their respective models, as well as the code where you try to add items to `@event.items`. That'll help us help you

Comment: Updated the question to add the left out models.

Comment: You included the migrations, not the models :) Although, based on the migrations, `item_datum` might actually be named `item_data`

Comment: Your `Event` migration does not need the `item_datum_id` foreign key. The foreign key belongs to the model which `belongs_to` its parent. `ItemDatum` needs an `event_id` column in its table (if it doesn't already)

Comment: `ItemDatum` does include an `event_id`, i'll try updating to `item_data`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84839/discussion-between-evan-ward-and-wes-foster).